# Dokan Wordpress Plugin Customization

Tags: wordpress, plugins

! am using the dokan wordpress plugin. want to allot each seller individually a market name . so that each seller associated with that market name. In one market there may be multiple seller How i proceed for that . please guide and provide me the code if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This feature included in dokan pro version 2.7.3, there is a new role name `vendor stuff` who could manage seller's store.